# No devices found with name or id matching 'linux'

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-linux

When I execute the command `flutter run -d linux` to run my flutter app on my Linux computer I get the following error

> No devices found with name or id matching 'linux'

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add support for your platform as stated in [Desktop support for Flutter](https://flutter.dev/desktop).

In case you are getting one of the following errors here are the fixes.

**For Linux:**

Error

> No devices found with name or id matching 'linux'

Fix

```
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
```

**For Windows:**

Error

> No devices found with name or id matching 'windows'

Fix

```
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
```

**For MacOS:**

Error

> No devices found with name or id matching 'macos'

Fix

```
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
```